# Автозапуск скрипта Python

Tags: python, api, автоматизация

Подскажите пожалуйста, в Jupyter Notebook написал скрипт, который выгружает данные по API и затем выгружает в таблицу. Мне нужно данный скрипт автоматизировать. То есть, чтобы например, каждый день в 10:00 скрипт выполнялся автоматически. Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

Используйте crontab. Минимальный интервал 1 минута

Конструктор запросов для crontab: [crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru/)